# How to set target XML doctype using boost::property_tree::write_xml?

Tags: boost, doctype, boost-propertytree

I would like to set the DOCTYPE of the generated XML document by `boost::property_tree::write_xml`:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
    using ptree = boost::property_tree::ptree;

    ptree pt;
    pt.put("ExampleKey", "ExampleValue");
    
    std::ofstream file("test.xml");
    boost::property_tree::write_xml(file, pt);

}
```

I tried with `xml_writer_settings` but there is very little (to be kind) useful documentation about it. So I am not even aware if it can help or if it purpose is totally different.

**How to set the DOCTYPE in the generated XML by `boost::property_tree::write_xml`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Boost Property Tree, unsurprisingly, is not an XML library. It's a property tree library.

To write XML, consider using an XML library: [What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c/9387612#9387612)

Then again, there is potentially a hack using undocumented interface: [removing encoding attribute from xml using boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448864/removing-encoding-attribute-from-xml-using-boost/47450605#47450605)

That way you effectively bypass the document writing code and you can substitute it with your own <strike>hack</strike>.